# Calculating conditional probability given two other variables

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume we have a `DataFrame` with some columns and I need to find the conditional probability of `A` given `B` and `C` (which are columns of this `DataFrame`) simultaneously. How do I calculate that? 

For one variable, that is finding the conditional probability of `A` given `B` this would be pretty straightforward, I can make a `groupby()` and then a `value_counts()` like this:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].value_counts() / df.groupby('A')['B'].count()
```

However, this won't work if I select 2 columns like this:

```
df.groupby('A')[['B', 'C']]
```

because this is then no longer a `SeriesGroupBy` object but rather a `DataFrameGroupBy` object and I can't apply the `value_counts()` function.

**Edit**

Example:

This is part of the `DataFrame` 
[image]>

This is the output if I want to find the conditional probability that a person survives given his traveling class:

[image]

Now, I want to find the conditional probability that a person survives given two variables, say his traveling class and sex.

Comment: Few points: Make sure the output is according to the input given in the question. Also [do not post images of data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: You're expected output still looks like groupby applied on single column

Comment: Yeah that gets me the expected output!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, just reverse your `groupby` pattern - groupby the conditions and apply `value_counts` to "survived":

```
df.groupby(['pclass', 'sex'])['survived'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

And if you need the output as a `DataFrame`, use [`Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df.groupby(['pclass', 'sex'])['survived'].value_counts(normalize=True).reset_index(name='prob')
```